# How do I reverse this following circuit, i.e. when the laser is off then it should stop buzzing?

Tags: integrated-circuit, power-electronics, optoelectronics

[image]

All the necessary symbols are given in the circuit itself. When the laser is shooted to photoresistor, then buzzer stops. I want to stop the buzzer as soon as laser gets off.

Answer (score 2):

Just swap your CDS component and the \$6.8k\Omega\$ resistor.

When the laser lights the CDS its resistance becomes very low, so the 2N7000 gate is tied to ground, so the mosfet is off and the buzzer is off too. When the CDS is not lit the \$6.8k\Omega\$ resistor ties the mosfet gate to \$V_{cc}\$ turning it on and turning on the buzzer (and the led).

If you swap the CDS and the \$6.8k\Omega\$ resistor the behaviour of your circuit will be inverted as you request.

Comment: You are wasting your time building synthesizers LOL +1

Comment: Why is that? I enjoy that project... Apart from the fact that sometimes it does not work.

Comment: I am teasing you LOL LOL

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure of what you mean... I mean, I understand what you are saying but not what you mean.

Comment: Because the question/answer is so simple I was implying that this should be your chosen path in engineering - I was teasing you and trying to be humerous and it didn't work :(

Comment: Ok now I get it :D Well that's an idea, anyway if I fail in EE i want to either become a pizza maker or a cook ;)